# Thread Join method

Tags: c#-3.0

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ParameterizedThreadStart aStart = new ParameterizedThreadStart(Addition);
            Thread aThread = new Thread(aStart);
            Data aData = new Data();
            aData.X = 10;
            aData.Y = 20;

        aThread.Start(aData);
        aThread.Join();
        Console.WriteLine("End of the program");
    }


    static void Addition(object data)
    {
        var a = data as Data;
        var b = a.X + a.Y;
        a.result = b;

        Console.WriteLine(a.result);
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("End of thread");

    }
}
```

I have written an example to understand the Join method(); 
Can any body explain how it works ? and what is the difference between sleep and join()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Join` waits until the thread you've called it on stops. `Sleep` sleeps for a given time period.

Comment: @ Ernest : As per the msdn : Thread join method() means : Blocks the calling thread until a thread terminates.    What does the calling thread means and how does the calling the thread comes to know that the thread is terminated ?

Comment: The "calling thread" is the one that calls `Join`. All code executes in a thread, even if you don't explicitly create any; `Main` runs in a thread created by the runtime for this purpose. As for how the calling thread knows that the other thread has exited: that's a primitive capability of the underlying thread library. I've never looked at the C# implementation, but in many threading libraries, there's a semaphore that a thread will signal when it exits. `Join` then just has to wait on that semaphore until notified.

Answer (score 1):

- `Thread.Sleep`

  Blocks the current thread for the specified number of milliseconds.

  -`Thread.Join`

  Blocks the calling thread until a thread terminates (you don't know for how long)

Note that the Thread.Join() method only blocks the calling thread (**usually the application's main thread of execution**) until your thread object completes. You can still have other threads executing in the background while waiting for your specific Thread to finish executing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join.aspx

Comment: until a threads means what? Thread which is created by the main thread.

Comment: if for example you start your thread from the main one .Join will make the Main thread wait that the one your have started complete its execution. In yuor example the Main will wait until the  aThread.Start(aData) will be completed

Answer (score 0):

It causes the currently running thread to stop execution till the time the thread it joins with stop execution.i.e joins method waits for a thread to die.